# Will changing my GitHub username make websites hosted on GitHub Pages inaccessible?

Tags: github, web, github-actions, github-pages, web-hosting

For example, will `abc.github.io/verbose/` (**abc** being my **current** username) be changed to `xyz.github.io/verbose/` when I change my username to **xyz**? Will it be automated through GitHub actions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you attempt to change your username on GitHub, they explicitly mention that **no redirects for GitHub Pages will be set up**. Therefore, all links pointing to `oldname.github.io/verbose/` will no longer work. It is even possible for someone else to register an account (or organisation) using your old username and then host their website there.

*Here is a screenshot of the dialog:*

[image: screenshot]

Comment: so i have to first un host and delete previous deployments and then host again once I change the username right?

Comment: @ransom I would strongly assume that existing deployments will be removed automatically. If you want to be sure, you can deactivate Pages first. It could be that manual intervention is needed to re-deploy after changing the username. However, you can easily activate this again or change the settings to match your needs. The most important thing to know beforehand is that there will be no redirect after changing the username and someone else might claim it.